# Scrapy: How to add parameters to each request with start_requests?

Tags: scrapy

I am using scrapy 2.1 where I scrapy content from category pages which are paginated. The default result set is 20 and I want to increase this to 1000 in order to request viewer pages.

e.g.

```
/category1
/category1?VIEW_SIZE=20&VIEW_INDEX=1
```

wanted:

```
/category1?VIEW_SIZE=1000&VIEW_INDEX=1
```

Rules:

```
rules = (
        # parse all index pages
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
            allow   = ['^.*\/[a-z-0-9]+(\?VIEW_SIZE=20&VIEW_INDEX=\d{0,3}&filterBy=default&sortBy=default)?(?<![\d])$'], 
            # deny=[''],
            restrict_xpaths=(['//aside[@id="aside-st"]', # navigation bar
                              '//ul[@class="page-lst"]/li[position()<last()]']), # include pagination     
            ),
                follow  = True,
                callback= 'parse_item'
        ),
    )
```

Overriding start_requests to add parameters to each URL requested:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={'VIEW_SIZE': 1000})
```

This does not work. How can I add to each URL I want to scrape the given parameters within the request?

Comment: To change the URL parameters, you need to change the `url` parameter to `Request`, `meta` is for metadata of your spider that never reaches the target server. To make URL editing easy you can use [`w3lib.url.add_or_replace_parameters`](https://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/w3lib.html#w3lib.url.add_or_replace_parameters).

Comment: OK, sounds like a plan. How about the URLs itself? Will start_requests be called on every URL discovered by the ruleset? There is only one start URL defined in my configuration, the root domain. All other URLs will be discovered by the crawlspider.

Comment: Use the `process_links` parameter of the `__init__` method of `CrawlSpider` for that.

Comment: Thank you @Gallaecio I solved the problem and added an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem of adding custom parameters to each request:

Add callback with the help of process_links to Rule:

```
rules = (
    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(
            allow=['^.*\/c\/.*'],
            # deny=[''],
            restrict_xpaths=(['//li[contains(@class, "navigation--entry")]', 
            ]), 
        ), 
        process_links='link_filtering',
        callback='parse_item',
        follow=True
    ),   
)
```

Add parameters to each URL

```
# gett max amount of results per category and add n=x results to url
def link_filtering(self, links):
    for link in links:
        link.url = "%s?p=1&n=1000" % link.url
    return links
```